# Wpf control overlap by winform controls

Tags: wpf, winforms, rich-text-editor

I have one problem in win-form/ desktop application. I am using WPF control in win-form application. I have richtext box in my application this text box is wpf richtext box.

When scroll the window page then richtext box is overlap by winform control 
I have attached two image one have issue and another is correct image

[image]

Above image have issue

[image]

Above image is correct